# Windows 7 Installation progress bar in VB Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image]

As you can see the progress bar there, I am trying to create that same progress bar in VB WinForms. I was able to find an image of the blue bar line and just put it into a picturebox on the form, but I can't get the shiny thing to come out. You can see the exact animation here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00nbQEvA1yg#t=10s

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a moving image type like gif or if you don't have a video version of loading animation, you simply have no way to get it moving properly. Only way would be creating a similar animation using DirectX or OpenGL from scratch or rendering a video of that and embedding it to your form, which are not simple at all.

Also you should not forget about copyright!

Comment: I am a student and this is just a small project so there won't be much copyright issue :D...Also, how did Microsoft create that then?

Comment: :( So I can't do it in vb or even C#?

Comment: I don't think so. Let's see if someone else has a solution. I am curious about it.

Comment: @user1079641 go with our gif idea it is easiest